# How to put a recyclerview inside another and receive data from the row selected?

Tags: java, android, arrays, xml, android-recyclerview

Hi guys i need some help in java im trying to make a recyclerview that have some items and i wanted whenever someone clicked on one item it took him to the other recyclerview but with the data i set it for ?? PLS HELP

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to send the data in this specific item.
in the recyclerview class
the list of the items presented in the recyclerview declare them as global variables.
and you will find this method

```
public void onBindViewHolder(Holderclass holder, final int position)
```

you can use this position variable to access that specific item in the list.
for example if you have arrayList "list" then.

```
list.get(position).
```

save the data in bundle and use putextra() to send it if it is a new intent or setarguments() if it is a new fragment, and then retrieve the data via getextra() or getarguments() in the new activity or fragment. repeat what you did with the first recyclerview

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks mohamed alot, but still have a question do we have to make for every item of the recyclerview a new recyclerview to show different list of items . Thanks in advance bro